# PHP filter_var() does not return values for false or 0

Tags: php, boolean

I have a problem in a PHP function due to an incorrect validation of true/false imput.
I found here a solution, which is to adopt filter_var to convert in boolean and check if input is valid.
Made a simple test page and php function to try; the function is correct in determining a 'true,1, on' values and it does return a correct '1'.
When submitting a '0, false' the function does not return '0' as expected; actually it returns nothing (even if a dump_var says it is a bool).
This is the simple test code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

$flag = $_GET['flag'];
$filter = filter_var($flag, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
echo "Flag: ".$flag."  ,  Filter: ".$filter;
```

Results for true and false or 1 and 0 inputs:
Flag: true - Filter: 1
Flag: false - Filter:

Where is my mistake?
(using PHP: 7.3.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `echo`ing a boolean it prints nothing if the value is `false`. It however still is a boolean, you can show the value using:

```
var_dump($filter);
```

or

```
if($filter){
  echo 'is true';
}else{
  echo 'is false';
}
```

or

```
echo $filter ? 'is true' : 'is false';
```

`var_dump` is recommended for debugging purposed because it also shows falsy values and more complicated structures like arrays nicely:

```
$array = [1,2,3];
var_dump($array);
```